# Как передать двоичные данные через микрофон телефона?

Tags: алгоритм, android

На смартфоне получена медицинская информация. Требуется передать её в диагностический центр. Но в этьй деревне нет сотовой связи - только старинный телефон. Android-программа должна преобразовать двоичные данные в звук и послать их в динамик смартфона. Смартфон приложен к телефонной трубке. На другом конце телефонной линии другой смартфон слушает писк и преобразует его в массив двоичных данных без потери точности.

Будем благодарны за любую информацию по этой теме.

Comment: Супер вопрос!

Answer (score 3):

На ходу: есть вариант кодировки бинарников через DTMF сигналы (по русски говоря сигналы тонового набора). С точки зрения кодирования бинарников на DTMF вроде ничего сложного нет - грубо говоря бинарник раскладывается на десятичный сигнал (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) каждой цифре сопоставлен определенный писк.

На том конце провода все сложнее. Стандартный API этого не поддерживает, но быстрое гугление приводит к проекту [DTMF декодер](https://code.google.com/p/dtmf-decoder/source/checkout)

Удачи!